# Add value of a cell to another cell for all cells in a column in Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to assign a script to the + button, such that when I press the button, cell M4 will be added with the value from cell R4, M5 with value from R5, and so on until the end of the column.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqSjW.jpg)

This is my script

```
function add() {
s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
var rangeVal=s.getRange("M:M")
var rangeVal2=s.getRange("R:R")
var Val=rangeVal.getValues()
var Val2=rangeVal2.getValues()
for (var i=4; i<Val.length; i++) {
if (Val2[i][0] > 0 ) {
  Val[i][0] = Val[i][0] + Val2[i][0]; } } 
rangeVal.setValues(Val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add() {
  s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var rangeVal=s.getRange("M:M")
  var rangeVal2=s.getRange("R:R")
  var Val=rangeVal.getValue() // <= you went wrong here
  var Val2=rangeVal2.getValue() // <= & here
  for (var i=4; i<Val.length; i++) {
    if (Val2[i][0] > 0 ) {
      Val[i][0] = Val + Val2; // <= & here
    } 
  } 
  rangeVal.setValue(Val); // <= & here
}
```

Just a few typos are stopping this working (some that i missed in my initial inspection!), otherwise the logic is correct.  You're calling `range.getValue()`, which returns the top left value of the range as a string, but you want to use [`range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) (with an 's' at the end of the function name) to retrieve all of the values in the range as a 2D array. You also need to use [`range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) at the end to write the values back to the spreadsheet.  Finally, you've very carefully stepped through the data arrays, but each time you loop you're concatenating `Val` & `Val2`. You need to add the specific values together: `Val[i][0] += Val2[i][0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated the script in my question. Still show empty cells though.

Comment: It works like a charm! I learnt something new today. Thanks :) Will update the script.